# Unable to install/uninstall pip - Linux

Tags: linux, rhel, python, yum, pip

When i try to uninstall pip, I am getting the error below

```
$python2.7 -m pip uninstall pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-21.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/__main__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main as _main
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-21.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 60
    sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I ran `whereis pip` to know the location it is installed. It returned

```
/usr/bin/pip /usr/bin/pip2.7
```

When I was trying to install pip, I tried `yum install python27-python-pip` and then `easy_install pip` by mistake from where it started to error out like this. How can I fix this ?

Comment: [Do *not* run `pip` as root](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/do-not-run-pip-as-root). Create virtualenv instead and run it inside.

Answer (score 0):

PIP community discontinued the support to 2.7. You will have to upgrade pip to latest version.

```
pip install -upgrade pip
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. You may want to add a link to the site where you found the discontinuation notice. Also, it might be of interest to other readers why the lack of python 2.7 support would lead to complains about a syntax error.

Comment: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/development/release-process/#python-2-support